# vSphere 5, trying to setup NAT

Tags: vmware-esxi, nat

I am new to using ESXi and vSphere, I currently have ESXi 5 running with a win 2008 server VM on it. I am trying to set it up so that the VM can access the internet by setting up NAT. I cannot find the option in vSphere and all of the documentation I have found doesn't offer much  help. I don't really understand the virtual switches and port groups and things like that.

I know in vmWare it was as simple as bridging the virtual adapter to the physical one.

Sorry if this is too in depth of a question.

EDIT: Adding more information.
I currently only have the one vm on the server. In the future I might be adding more to it and I would like all VM based traffic to look like its coming from the ESXi ip address (through NAT).

Comment: Are you trying to put your VMware ESXi host actually onto the Internet unprotected? I would let the firewall do the NAT instead.

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean. I am trying to set it up so that the windows VM generates traffic that looks like it is coming from the ESXi's ip address.

Comment: If your ESXi server is protected from the Internet by a firewall, then you don't need to make the Windows VM act that way; VMware creates its own interfaces for each of the VMs separately. You don't need to NAT the way you are suggesting. However, if you are trying to put this host on the Internet without protection, then you are asking for trouble: you should put ESXi behind a firewall.

Comment: That's not how it works.

Comment: Put another way: why do you want to NAT the Windows VM? It will work just fine on any network without NAT.

Comment: Currently, I don't have access to our IP address list and so I don't know which IP to assign to the VM's. I know the exact IP used for the server.

Comment: Set your server to use DHCP then, and accept the assigned address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP of the management interface has nothing to do with the IPs of the VMs on it. The fact that, in your setup, the vmkernel port may also be on the same physical port as the vmnetwork doesn't mean anything. Basically, you can't do what you think you can do.

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'll just have to wait until I have our IP address list to figure out which ones aren't in use.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in ESXi to connect a VM, one-click (with no effort), by connecting the VM through a virtual sub-network with a virtual "router/gateway" that implements DHCP/NAT (the NAT permits the VMs to access the outer network with the host IP). I verified this statement with a friend of mine that works on ESX since 7 years.

This feature (to connect a VM through a NAT-ed network automatically, one-click) exists in "Virtualbox" and "VMWare Workstation", but ESX--and other *production* hypervisors like Xenserver and Proxmox--has not this feature.

The alternative solution in, ESXi/Xenserver/Proxmox, is to create a vSwitch only for the Nat-ed VMs but you need to prepare a VM connected both to this vSwitch and to the local network (VM must have 2 NICs) and configure it for the gateway/NAT role (e.g., use the PfSense distro). Yes, the gateway VM needs at least one IP in the local network. But this is not a "one-click" solution.